# Counting preg_match in smarty

Tags: preg-match, smarty

How to count preg_match matches in smarty? Why is the following not working?

```
{preg_match("/\[PGN.*](.*)\[\/PGN.*\]/", $code, $match)}

{$match|@count}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the content of `$code`? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: $code = "[PGN1]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN1]

[PGN2]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN2]

[PGN3]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN3]

[PGN4]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN4]

[PGN5]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN5]

[PGN6]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN6]

[PGN7]1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6[/PGN7]"

So I would to expect the answer 7. But somehow I get "1 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your needs, the following does work, just make the regex not greedy:

```
preg_match_all("~\[PGN\d+](.+?)\[/PGN\d+]~", $code, $match)
```

Comment: Thanks, but {$match|@count} displays 0 :(

Comment: @EmanuelSchiendorfer: Sorry, I've made a typo, use `preg_match_all`. See my edit.